# Avoiding collisions with other objects while moving an Agent to a specific destination

Tags: anylogic

I have in my model some free-moving agents, which travel to specific nodes. I use the function...

```
moveTo(node)
```

...to specify the node an agent should visit. Using this function, the agent travels the shortest path to the node. However, the model layout contains areas (i.e. image files), which the agent should not pass. Right now, the agents may travel through these areas to reach their destination. Now I'm wondering, whether there is an easy way to permit an agent to enter specific areas in the model, when traveling to a node.

I already took a look at the example model "Wandering Elephants" where the elephants are permitted to walk through areas with water. The solution there is, that if an elephant meets water in the direction it's currently heading, it randomly searches for another direction, until it finds one without water. However, this approach doesn't really fit to my problem, as the elephants in the model wander around without any specific destination. I'm searching for a method, which works for an agent that travels to a specific point. In the best case, the agent would search the shortest path around the obstacle to reach its destination.

**Edit 1:** The following figure shows my problem in a nutshell. On the left side is my model structure, while on the right side the state chart of my custom agent. What is happening in the model: The 3 sources are producing agents, which will be delayed for an uncertain time (delay stops with stopDelay()). Everytime an agent enters a delay, the delay is added to the collection request. My customagent check requests in a loop until the collection contains at least one request. Then, the customagent randomly selects a request (i.e. delay object) to serve. Each delay is associated with a node (the  collection processNodes maps delays to nodes). Now, I want to cast my customagent to a Transporter and move it to the corresponding node. The agent should avoid collisions with the stripped walls in the model. I want to avoid any seizing and releasing of resources. I just want to adapt the behaviour of the Transport agent from the material handling library to my agent.

**Edit 2:**
In my current testbed, my custom agent does not  consider node 1 or node 2. For testing, the agent should only try to reach node without any collisions.

[image: AnyLogic model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a sufficient work-around. Not exactly what I wanted, but it works. Against my initial intention, I use now seize and release for transports. However, I added a hold-block in front of each seized-block and only a resource, which decides to serve the process, is able to unblock the corresponding hold. The on-enter control of the unblocked hold ensures that the hold is directly blocked again as soon as a single agent flows through. For the case that other users are also interested in the solution, I attached the flow-chart of the process and the state-chart of the Transporter-Agent. The system structure is quite the same as in my initial question.

[image: Flow-Chart]

[image: State-Chart]

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in way unless you use transporters from the Material handling library (or pedestrians). These can do what you need.

So easiest might be to convert you agents to transporters temporarily.

Otherwise, you will have to code something yourself...

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I tried to implement your idea, but so far it does not work. What I have done so far: (1) Created a Transporter Type Agent from the Material Handling Library called Transporter (2) Added some walls in the model to describe the area, which the agent shall avoid (3) changed the moveTo statement in the agents state chart to "((Transporter)this).moveTo(node);" However, AnyLogic reports the following error "Cannot cast from CustomAgent to Transporter" (CustomAgents are my agents I actually want to move). Any idea, how  to avoid this error? Thanks Sebastian

Comment: you must use the MoveTo element from the Material-handling library "Move by transporter":-) Check some example models as well, always helpful

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I  already checked  several example models from the material handling library, but it's hard for me to bring everything together. The main problem is that all example models from the material handling library are using the MoveByTransporter object from the library within their process flow  chart. Actually, I really want to avoid this, as I don't want any seizing  and releasing of resources. I was experimenting with type-casting according to your answer. However, I always get the same errors. I edited my question above and provided more details. Maybe you can give me a last hint.

Comment: First: Why do you need collision avoidance in the first place? Is there a good reason beyond 'it looks good" and "this is what happens in reality" ? Neither are good enough for models :-)  Second: Why not use seizing and releasing? AnyLogic only gets really powerful when you combine different paradigms/libraries so don"t shy away but embrace it :-)

Comment: 1) The process I want to model is a fixed-position assembly system. By this means, I have a product with large dimensions on a fixed position, while the assembly process is conducted by mobile workers, who move around the product and perform several tasks. It's important that the workers do not cross the product to travel from spot to spot. Due to the large dimensions of the product, transport times to move from spot to spot are important to consider.

Comment: 2) I want to avoid seize and release as the resource is in that case kind of passive, i.e. it "obeys" the requesting resource. However, in the system, the assembly process is not really standardized. More precisely, the workers (the resource agents) can choose which assembly task to perform next. The choice what to do next is usually subject to personal preferences. Therefore, I want that the agent decides which process to serve next. My plan is to implement in my resource agent a kind of decision making model, which considers those personal references for choosing the next task.